# Txt - to - csv using spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I want to take data from txt file and send it to csv file. what should be the code in spring batch. below is the mentioned code for both reader and writer. please help . I'm able to pass csv to csv in spring batch. what is the exact code in item reader.

```java
public class RecordsReader {

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Records> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Records> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("C://output/pip-1.7.txt"));
        reader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper());
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        return reader;
    }

    private LineMapper<Records> getLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<Records> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(Records.fields());
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Records> fieldSetter = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetter.setTargetType(Records.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetter);

        return lineMapper;
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Any exception you see?

Answer (score 0):

Your LineMapper will look like -

```
public class RecordsLineMapper implements LineMapper<Records> {


  private static final Pattern PATTERN =
  Pattern.compile(
      "^(?<recordId>[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,20})"
          + "(?<value1>[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,50})"
          + "$");

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public Records mapLine(@NonNull String line, int lineNumber) {
   // Match the Line
   Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(line);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Line at " + lineNumber + " does not match pattern");
    }


    Records records = new Records();
    records.setRecordId(matcher.group("recordId"));
    records.setValue1(matcher.group("value1"));
    return records;
 }
}
```

The FlatFileItemReader bean look like -

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Records> recordsFlatFileItemReader(
  RecordsLineMapper mapper) {
  return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Records>()
    .name("records-reader")
    .lineMapper(mapper)
    .build();
}
```

You can now validate the record in the processor and add a writer to it.

Writer Implementation

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<Records> recordsToCsvFileItemWriter(
  @Qualifier("csvFile") File csvFile,
  RecordsLineAggregator aggregator) {
return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Records>()
    .name("records-to-csv-item-writer")
    .saveState(false)
    .resource(new FileSystemResource(csvFile))
    .lineAggregator(aggregator)
    .build();
 }


public class RecordsLineAggregator implements LineAggregator<Records> {

 @Override
 @NonNull
 public String aggregate(Records item) {
 return new StringJoiner(",")
     .add(item.getRecordId())
     .add(item.getValue1())
     .toString();
   }
 }
```

Comment: sorry i didnt understand

Comment: how should i edit the item reader code of mine.

Comment: It's a similar way I did create the reader bean and provide the LineMapper.